# Timeout for first slide in slideshow not working (lasts almost double other slides)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow, responsive-slides

I am using a responsive slideshow (http://responsiveslides.com/) for some testimonials on a website with the following settings:

```
jQuery(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
  auto: true,             // Boolean: Animate automatically, true or false
  speed: 100,            // Integer: Speed of the transition, in milliseconds
  timeout: 10000,          // Integer: Time between slide transitions, in milliseconds
  pager: false,           // Boolean: Show pager, true or false
  nav: true,             // Boolean: Show navigation, true or false
  random: false,          // Boolean: Randomize the order of the slides, true or false
  pause: true,           // Boolean: Pause on hover, true or false
  pauseControls: true,    // Boolean: Pause when hovering controls, true or false
  prevText: "Previous",   // String: Text for the "previous" button
  nextText: "Next",       // String: Text for the "next" button
  maxwidth: "",           // Integer: Max-width of the slideshow, in pixels
  navContainer: "",       // Selector: Where controls should be appended to, default is after the 'ul'
  manualControls: "",     // Selector: Declare custom pager navigation
  namespace: "rslides",   // String: Change the default namespace used
  before: function(){},   // Function: Before callback
  after: function(){}     // Function: After callback
});
```

However, the first slide lasts almost double the other slides. Does anyone know how to fix this or why it is happening? Any help would be really appreciated!

You can see the error at this page: http://www.hbprojectsltd.co.uk/testimonials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because you have the same testimonial twice.

If you look at the source code for the page, it shows that the first testimonial is exactly the same as the second. The slide animation is happening but because it looks the same, it looks as if nothing has happened.

See here (line 97 - 110):

```
<li>
  <blockquote class="testiquote">I have worked with HB Projects for circa 10 years although the company has worked for ASDA for significantly longer than that. HB are a mainstay of the ASDA Construction supplier base and have a turnover with us of circa £20m p.a. I have always found
    the team at HB Projects to be proactive, innovative and forward thinking. The quality of their work is always of a high standard and they always deliver on time and to cost. Snagging is resolved quickly and efficiently. Colleagues and Management undergo
    rigorous training and can be trusted to ensure individuals have appropriate qualifications for the level of work involved.
    <br />
    <br />I would be happy to give my full endorsement to HB Projects to undertake any schemes you have planned. I can confirm they have the skill-set to undertake all facets of construction work, from design to build and management of your project. I have
    always found the HB team honest and trustworthy. They have helped us deliver our mission to be Britain’s best value retailer and are considered a true partner to ASDA.
  </blockquote>
  <div class="endtestiquote"></div>
  <div class="quotefrom">
    <p><span class="bluefont bold">Richard Wilson</span>
      <br />Construction Manager, Construction & Facilities, Property & Format Development, Asda House.</p>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <blockquote class="testiquote">I have worked with HB Projects for circa 10 years although the company has worked for ASDA for significantly longer than that. HB are a mainstay of the ASDA Construction supplier base and have a turnover with us of circa £20m p.a. I have always found
    the team at HB Projects to be proactive, innovative and forward thinking. The quality of their work is always of a high standard and they always deliver on time and to cost. Snagging is resolved quickly and efficiently. Colleagues and Management undergo
    rigorous training and can be trusted to ensure individuals have appropriate qualifications for the level of work involved.
    <br />
    <br />I would be happy to give my full endorsement to HB Projects to undertake any schemes you have planned. I can confirm they have the skill-set to undertake all facets of construction work, from design to build and management of your project. I have
    always found the HB team honest and trustworthy. They have helped us deliver our mission to be Britain’s best value retailer and are considered a true partner to ASDA.
  </blockquote>
  <div class="endtestiquote"></div>
  <div class="quotefrom">
    <p><span class="bluefont bold">Richard Wilson</span>
      <br />Construction Manager, Construction & Facilities, Property & Format Development, Asda House.</p>
  </div>
</li>
```

You'll just need to remove one of the blockquotes and your problem should be fixed.